# Language problem

Tags: undergraduate

I'm finding it hard to understand my lecturers in lectures because they do lecture in Arabic language which I do not know.  So please how can I make it to the pillar of success? 
I'm currently at Suez University, Egypt pursuing degree in petroleum and mining engineering. 
Your advises are highly appreciated 
Thanks

Comment: What languages do you know?

Comment: Is it a dialect you don't understand, or a completely different language? Are they teaching in the country's/location's main language?

Answer (score 11):

Two options:

1. Learn the language. You should realize that if you choose to study at a university whose language of instruction is something you're unfamiliar with, you are also choosing to learn the language. There's no other way about it. It's unusual that the university didn't make sure you're familiar with Arabic or at least arrange Arabic courses for you before admitting you, however.
2. Study somewhere else. You can self-teach to some extent, but it's not a long term solution and you won't be able to pass the assignments / exams. Apply for a transfer to another university that teaches in a language you do know.

Comment: This. I really wonder what more than these options OP hoped for.

Answer (score 3):

I studied in a second language, but I had at least a good grounding in it... and it was still very very challenging : this was engineering as well (not the same focus and  issues as studying languages).

Best option IMHO is to move, unless you can become very proficient in that language in two months.